# Click toggle with jQuery

Tags: jquery, onclick, toggle

I've used a hover function where you do x on mouseover and y and mouseout. I'm trying the same for click but it doesn't seem to work:

```
$('.offer').click(function(){ 
  $(this).find(':checkbox').attr('checked', true ); 
},function(){
  $(this).find(':checkbox').attr('checked', false ); 
});
```

I want the checkbox to be checked when clicking on a `div`, and unchecked if clicked again - a click toggle.

Comment: Here is tutorial on [How to create JQuery plugin to convert radio buttons into toggle buttons](http://sgeek.org/jquery-toggle-button-plugin-for-sliding-toggle-switches-sswitch/) and [Here you can see demo](http://www.demos.sgeek.org/sswitch-jquery-plugin-demo/). Hopefully it may help you or other users

Answer (score 214, accepted):

This is easily done by flipping the current 'checked' state of the checkbox upon each click. Examples:

```
 $(".offer").on("click", function () { 
       var $checkbox = $(this).find(':checkbox');
       $checkbox.attr('checked', !$checkbox.attr('checked'));
 });
```

or:

```
 $(".offer").on("click", function () { 
       var $checkbox = $(this).find(':checkbox');
       $checkbox.attr('checked', !$checkbox.is(':checked'));
 });
```

or, by directly manipulating the DOM 'checked' property (i.e. not using `attr()` to *fetch* the current state of the clicked checkbox):

```
 $(".offer").on("click", function () { 
       var $checkbox = $(this).find(':checkbox');
       $checkbox.attr('checked', !$checkbox[0].checked);
 });
```

...and so on.

Note: since jQuery 1.6, checkboxes should be set using `prop` not `attr`:

```
 $(".offer").on("click", function () { 
       var $checkbox = $(this).find(':checkbox');
       $checkbox.prop('checked', !$checkbox[0].checked);
 });
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend setting an element's DOM attribute to a boolean value. Presumably it gets cast to the string `'1'` in the process.

Comment: @Alex Barrett - shouldn't matter, jQuery sweeps such details under the rug. I believe it's common practice to set boolean attributes like *selected*, *disabled* and *checked* to a boolean value using attr(). Furthermore, their internal representation is boolean, alert($foo.attr('checked')) will return true or false whether or not a string or a boolean has been used to set it.

Comment: I've encountered cases where you actually need to remove the "checked" attribute completely in order for the box to be unchecked.  In those circumstances, none of these will work.

Comment: @Jeremy - can you provide a working example? Sounds like a bizarre edge case.

Comment: As I recall, it was an edge case, and very frustrating to track down.  Unfortunately I don't remember the details, and I no longer work in the environment I discovered it.  I just thought I'd mention it in case someone else ran across the issue while implementing your answer.

Comment: Why invert the attribute in such a complex way, when you can just click on each checkbox:
`...
$(this).find(':checkbox').click();
...`

Answer (score 27):

Another approach would be to extended jquery like this:

```
$.fn.toggleCheckbox = function() {
    this.attr('checked', !this.attr('checked'));
}
```

Then call:

```
$('.offer').find(':checkbox').toggleCheckbox();
```

Comment: I like that, as it works for trainloads of checkboxes, too. +1

Comment: You should add `this.trigger('change');` otherwise the onChange Event wont be triggered.

Answer (score 11):

Warning: using **attr()** or **prop()** to change the state of a checkbox **does not** fire the **change event** in most browsers I've tested with. The checked state will change but no event bubbling. You must trigger the change event manually after setting the checked attribute. I had some other event handlers monitoring the state of checkboxes and they would work fine with direct user clicks. However, setting the checked state programmatically fails to consistently trigger the change event.

jQuery 1.6

```
$('.offer').bind('click', function(){ 
    var $checkbox = $(this).find(':checkbox');
    $checkbox[0].checked = !$checkbox[0].checked;
    $checkbox.trigger('change'); //<- Works in IE6 - IE9, Chrome, Firefox
});
```

Comment: you could also trigger the click event directly.

Answer (score 7):

You could use the [`toggle`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/toggle) function:

```
$('.offer').toggle(function() {
    $(this).find(':checkbox').attr('checked', true);
}, function() {
    $(this).find(':checkbox').attr('checked', false);
});
```

Comment: This has been deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

Why not in one line?

```
$('.offer').click(function(){
    $(this).find(':checkbox').attr('checked', !$(this).find(':checkbox').attr('checked'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a single checkbox named `chkDueDate` and an HTML object with a click event as follows:

```
$('#chkDueDate').attr('checked', !$('#chkDueDate').is(':checked'));
```

Clicking the HTML object (in this case a `<span>`) toggles the checked property of the checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery: Best Way, delegate the actions to jQuery (jQuery = jQuery).

```
$( "input[type='checkbox']" ).prop( "checked", function( i, val ) {
    return !val;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing this:

```
$(this).find(':checkbox').attr('checked', true );
```

to this:

```
$(this).find(':checkbox').attr('checked', 'checked');
```

Not 100% sure if that will do it, but I seem to recall having a similar problem.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.offer').click(function(){ 
    if ($(this).find(':checkbox').is(':checked'))
    {
        $(this).find(':checkbox').attr('checked', false); 
    }else{
        $(this).find(':checkbox').attr('checked', true); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In JQuery I don't think that click() accepts two functions for toggling. You should use the toggle() function for that: http://docs.jquery.com/Events/toggle

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.offer').click(function() { 
    $(':checkbox', this).each(function() {
        this.checked = !this.checked;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<label>
    <input
        type="checkbox"
        onclick="$('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));"
    />
    Check all
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution

```
$('.offer').click(function(){
    var cc = $(this).attr('checked') == undefined  ? false : true;
    $(this).find(':checkbox').attr('checked',cc);
});
```

Comment: Close. It will be 'undefined' on the first click, assigning the value 'false'. Then it will be defined on the second click, assigning the value 'true'. On a third click, it will still be defined, so it will still be assigned 'true'.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative solution to toggle checkbox value:

```
<div id="parent">
    <img src="" class="avatar" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="" />
</div>


$("img.avatar").click(function(){

    var op = !$(this).parent().find(':checkbox').attr('checked');
    $(this).parent().find(':checkbox').attr('checked', op);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('controlCheckBox').click(function(){
    var temp = $(this).prop('checked');
    $('controlledCheckBoxes').prop('checked', temp);
});
```