# jQuery toggle checkbox when parent is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, toggle, prop

I have written a simple js function to toggle the checkbox on/off then the parent (in this case a TD) is clicked. This function *works as expected when you click anywhere on the TD*.

However when you *click on the checkbox itself*, nothing happens.
**What I would like to know is *why* it does this and what's the best work around?**

[I have a provided a jsfiddle to demo this.](http://jsfiddle.net/V7LxV/)

And here is my js function:

```
$("td.onoff").click(function() {
    var objCheckbox = $(this).find("input[type=checkbox]");
    if( objCheckbox.length >= 1 ) {
        objCheckbox.prop("checked", !objCheckbox.prop("checked"));
    }
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467228/click-toggle-with-jquery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to `by pass event code when source of event is not td with class onoff`, You can do this way.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/V7LxV/4/)**

```
$(function() {
    $("td.onoff").click(function(event) {          
        if(event.target.className != 'onoff') return;
        var objCheckbox = $(this).find("input[type=checkbox]");
        if( objCheckbox.length >= 1 ) {
            objCheckbox.prop("checked", !objCheckbox.prop("checked"));
        }
    });
});
```

​

Answer (score 1):

check the type of clicked element. Without this, you are trying to get an element that not exist.

```
$(function() {
    $("td.onoff").click(function() {
        var type = $(this).attr('type');
        if ( type != "checkbox" ) {
            var objCheckbox = $(this).find("input[type=checkbox]");
            if( objCheckbox.length >= 1 ) {
                objCheckbox.prop("checked", !objCheckbox.prop("checked"));
            }
        }
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason it behaves in this way is because the `input` is triggering the parent `click` event, at which point `this` becomes the checkbox, and not the clicked `td`, so `.find("input[type=checkbox]")` won't select anything, and therefore no action will be performed.

An alternative to the other answers would be to bind the `click` event to the input directly, and stop it from propagating, eg:

```
$("td.onoff > input").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();        
});
```

[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/V7LxV/7/)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, and nice solution too +1. Decided to use @Adil's solution though, did the job in one line and in this instance it's easier for me to manage my js file with his solution.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following:

```
$("td.onoff :checkbox").click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

This prevents the click event from bubbling up to the container when you click on the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Use "for"   attribute rather than any javascript function
This will automatically work as it does by function:
Just below html:

```
<tr class="row" >
        <td class="onoff" ><label for="check1"><input id="check1" type="checkbox" name="something[]" checked="checked" /></label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
        <td class="onoff"><label for="check2"><input id="check2" type="checkbox" name="something[]" checked="checked" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
        <td class="onoff"><label for="check3"><input id="check3" type="checkbox" name="something[]" checked="checked" /></td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: Nice alternative to js, unfortunately this project will require lots of various sized tables generated dynamically. It's easier to slap a class on a td rather than adding in extra mark-up and code to deal with unique identifiers.